# Translation of "real estate"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, vocabulario

I have read that "real estate" can be translated as:

- bienes raíces
- bienes inmuebles
- inmuebles

What is the difference between these terms, and which is the most generic translation of "real estate"?

Comment: In Mexico, I see bienes raíces most often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bienes raíces* is the most used one in Chile. According to the dictionary, *bienes inmuebles* is the same as *bienes raíces*, but I couldn't say how widespread is each of them in other places.

*Real estate broker* is *agente de bienes raíces*. Note that *broker* is used as *agent*. Also *agente inmobiliario* (or *agente de inmuebles*, see last paragraph).

Another translation for *real estate broker* is *corredor de bienes raíces* or *corredor de propiedades* (and I guess that *corredor de bienes inmuebles* is also correct). When the context is clear, you might just say "corredor". That is, when there's no way of mistaking a *corredor (*de propiedades*) for a *corredor* (runner, athlete) or a *corredor de bolsa* (stockbroker).

A *propiedad* is just a property, both in the sense of a possession and of a quality. A house, for example, is *a* property, and a herb may have medicinal properties (*una yerba puede tener propiedades medicinales*). That's why *corredor de propiedades* is another name for a broker. However, I have not heard *agente de propiedades*, though it might be correct as well.

*Inmueble* is a house, or, more generally speaking, any inhabitable building. It is **not** the same as real estate, since *inmueble* is countable and *real estate* is uncountable.

Comment: Roughly the same in Argentina.

Comment: In Colombia the term `Finca Raíz` is more often used.

Answer (score 6):

All tree translations are correct for “real estate”, although the most common in Spain is just  *propiedad* (*propiedad inmobiliaria* to disambiguate) or *inmueble*. On the other hand *bienes raíces* is rarely used in Spain.

For “real estate” used in adjective phrase would be *inmobiliario*.

Full translation for real estate agency would be *agencia inmobiliaria*, however most often word *agencia* is dropped, thus you just call it *inmobiliaria*.

General term for real estate registry is *registro de la propiedad*, however the one in Spain is called *el Catastro* (formally *el Catastro Inmobiliario*).

Answer (score 2):

In the Dominican Republic is widely used Bienes Raices/Real Estate.  Agencia Inmobiliaria for Broker Agency or Real Estate Agency. I'm not familiar with the term Bienes Inmuebles; though in the DR it is rather used Bienes Inmobiliarios.